# Checking for Proper Subsets

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, subset

I need a function that can check if a list `a` is a proper subset of a list `b`.  My code so far is:

```
(defun proper-subset (a b)
    (cond
    (( or (null b)(null b)) nil)
    ((equal a b) nil)
    ((find (car a) b) (proper-subset (cdr a) b))
   )
)
```

`find` checks that each element of `a` is in `b`. I know the null arguments need some work as well, but I am trying to figure out how to determine when every element of `a` is found in `b` and `b` has another element. There are built in functions that can make this a lot easier however this a homework question so I have to write my own. Any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?  Since it's a homework assignment (clarified in the comments), I expect that you eventually had to turn in something.  Perhaps (without giving away the exact answer) you can post an answer that would help someone who finds this question in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below only adds `if` to the set of operations you mention, but this is really an atrocious way to do it. If that's what they teach you (you didn't volunteer for it). It's about time you get some good book on Lisp and study it yourself. This exercise is really pointless in my opinion.

```
(defun purge (element from-list)
  (if (null from-list) nil
      (if (equal element (car from-list))
          (purge element (cdr from-list))
          (cons (car from-list) (purge element (cdr from-list))))))

(defun proper-subset-p (suspect of)
  (if (null suspect) (not (null of))
      (if (not (equal (purge (car suspect) of) of))
          (proper-subset-p
           (purge (car suspect) suspect)
           (purge (car suspect) of)) nil)))
```

---

Same thing, but with `cond`

```
(defun purge (element from-list)
  (cond
    ((null from-list) nil)
    ((equal element (car from-list)) (purge element (cdr from-list)))
    (t (cons (car from-list) (purge element (cdr from-list))))))

(defun proper-subset-p (suspect of)
  (cond
    ((null suspect) (not (null of)))
    ((not (equal (purge (car suspect) of) of))
     (proper-subset-p (purge (car suspect) suspect) (purge (car suspect) of)))
    (t nil)))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the direction I was thinking. I am however having some trouble converting it to work with _cond_. Mainly figuring out the base case for the _proper-subset-p_. The way I read it is if after the first element of _supsect_ is removed from _of_ and not equal to _of_ then call a recursive call on _proper-subset-p_ and removing the first element of _suspect_ from _suspect_ and _of_ and then returning nill? I'm sorry if that sounded confusing I am just having trouble following it I think. We didn't go over if so that may just be why I am having a hard time.

Comment: @user2802966 It might sound strange, but I should really discourage you from using the code above :) It is written in this way only to meet the *strange* requirement you have. Put in plain English, it first checks that if you remove the first element of the `suspect` from `of`, `of` becomes smaller (which will confirm that it had the first element of `suspect` at least once). If after this step there are no more elements in `of`, you've confirmed that `suspect` is a proper subset. If both lists aren't `nil`, repeat the procedure.

Comment: The problems with the approach above are as follows: lists are not suited to represent sets, they allow repetition of elements, they also algorithmically poorly suited because of growing time needed to access elements. In real life, using a `hash-table` is in most cases the best straight-forward way to represent sets. You would never use lists to do what this task implies, unless lists are very short and the performance isn't important (source code manipulations for example).

Comment: It is just a very brief overview of LISP so I assume the lack of time to go over in-depth the built in functions is why it must be done in such an inefficient way. Thank you for the help though. I think I can get it work with _cond_.

Comment: @user2802966 well, for starters, `(if a b c)` is equivalent to `(cond (a b) (t c))`, so you could just mechanically replace `if` with `cond` where you need it.

Comment: Having some trouble getting it to work with _cond_. I think it is my _not equal_ case. I have _((not(equal (purge (car suspect) of) of)) t)_ which I think is the problem. My base case is _(t(proper-subset-p (purge (car suspect) suspect)(purge (car suspect) of)))_ which I'm fairly certain is fine. As of right now the problem I am having is the function always returns T because of the _not equal_ but I am not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Common Lisp defines a number of functions for working with lists as sets, so you don't need to write your own.  In particular, the useful functions appear at the bottom of [The Conses Dictionary](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/c_conses.htm).   The particularly useful ones are

- [`set-difference`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_set_di.htm), [`nset-difference`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_set_di.htm)
- [`set-exclusive-or`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_set_ex.htm), [`nset-exclusive-or`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_set_ex.htm)
- [`subsetp`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_subset.htm)
- [`union`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_unionc.htm), [`nunion`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_unionc.htm)

[`subsetp`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_subset.htm) *almost* does what you want, but it's checking for non-proper subsets.  However, observe that you can use these functions to compute what you need.  The most direct way would be to check if *A* is a subset of *B*, and whether *B - A ≠ {}*.   This matches your description, "every element of a is found in b and b has another element".

```
(defun proper-subsetp (a b)
  (and (subsetp a b)                       ; every element of a is found in b
       (not (endp (set-difference b a))))) ; b has another element
```

```
CL-USER> (proper-subsetp '(1 2 3) '(1 2 3 4))
T
CL-USER> (proper-subsetp '(1 2 3 4) '(1 2 3 4))
NIL
```

Since these functions actually take some parameters that let you determine how elements are compared.  You can add these in by using an `&rest` argument and apply:

```
(defun proper-subsetp (a b &rest keys)
  (and (apply 'subsetp a b keys )
       (not (endp (apply 'set-difference b a keys)))))
```

Using this, you could, rather than comparing the elements directly, compare their lengths:

```
CL-USER> (proper-subsetp '("a" "bb" "ccc") '("1" "22" "333") :key 'length)
NIL
CL-USER> (proper-subsetp '("a" "bb" "ccc") '("1" "22" "333" "4444") :key 'length)
T
```

Comment: I'm sorry I should have provided more information. This is a homework assignment so that is why I am trying to write my own. The functions we have at our disposal are (atom not null car cdr list cons append equal). I thought of maybe writing a remove function that removes all elements found in both lists and check to see if b is not null but I haven't gotten anywhere with it.

Comment: You should update your question with this information.  It significantly changes the types of answers that you're looking for. Also, people often respond negatively to homework questions that aren't labelled as such.

Comment: Edited it with the changes. Sorry, wasn't trying to mislead anyone.

Comment: @user2802966 your goal is not possible to achieve because the vocabulary of terms you listed does not include any conditional constructs, neither it has any means to process lists of arbitrary length. You need to either extend the vocabulary with something like `if` or `cond` and allow to at least declare custom functions (so that you could recursively traverse lists).

Comment: @wvxvw I suspect, given the code that user2802966 already has, that `cond` is allowed.  Oftentimes, the distinction between functions and macros and special operators isn't clear to beginners, or isn't made clear by casual instructors, but in this case, the list atom, not, null, car, cdr, list, cons, append, and equal actually is a list of functions.  It looks like `defun` and `or` are also allowed. ;)